# transform HList into another HList

Tags: scala, shapeless

I'm trying to convert a case class into another via conversion to HList.

```
case class Source(p1:S1, p2:S2) -> HList[S1:+:S2] -> HList[D1:+:D2] ->case class Destination(p1:D1,p2:D2)
```

I can convert from Source to HList via gem.to and from HList to Destination via gen.from.
I wrote a Converter for each type of parameter on Source to convert it to its corresponding type in Destination but I am unsure how to recursively traverse the HList. My attempt is shown below in `hlistEncoder`

```
trait Converter[T] {
  def convert(t:T): Datastructure
}
object Converter {
  implicit object StrDatastructure extends Converter[String]{
    def convert(t:String) = Datastructure.Str(t)
  }
  implicit object NumDatastructure extends Converter[Double]{
    def convert(t :Double) = Datastructure.Num(t)
  }
  implicit object IncDatastructure extends Converter[Inc]{
    def convert(t :Inc) = Datastructure.Incc(t)
  }
  implicit def SeqDatastructure[T: Converter]: Converter[Seq[T]] = new Converter[Seq[T]]{
    def convert(t: Seq[T]) = {
      Datastructure.Listt(t.map(implicitly[Converter[T]].convert):_*)
    }
  }

  //HList traversals

  implicit object hnilDatastructure extends Converter[HNil]{
    def convert(t: HNil) = Datastructure.Hnill(t)
  }

  implicit def hlistEncoder[H, T <: HList](implicit
                                            hEncoder: Converter[H],
                                            tEncoder: Converter[T]
                                          ): Converter[H :: T] = new Converter[H :: T] {
    def apply(h:H, t:T)= {
      case (h :: t) => hEncoder.convert(h) ++ tEncoder.convert(t)
    }

  }

}
```

I use this method to test HList to HList conversion

```
def convertToDatastructureN[T](x: T)(implicit converter: Converter[T]): Datastructure = {
  converter.convert(x)
}

case class Inc(i:Int)
case class Source(i: Int, n:Inc)

val x = Generic[Source]
val xHlist = x.to(Source(99, Inc(5)))
convertToDatastructureN(xHlist)
```

Any ideas how to implement `hlistEncoder`?

Answer (score 3):

I guess you have

```
sealed trait Datastructure
object Datastructure {
  case class Str(t: String) extends Datastructure
  case class Num(t: Double) extends Datastructure
  case class Incc(t: Inc) extends Datastructure
  case class Listt(t: Datastructure*) extends Datastructure
  case class Hnill(t: HNil) extends Datastructure
}
```

You want your type class `Converter` to transform `T` into `Datastructure`. But also (`HList[S1:+:S2] -> HList[D1:+:D2]`, where I guess `::` should be instead of `:+:`) you want subtypes of `HList` to be transformed into subtypes of `HList` (not into `HList` itself since otherwise `Generic` can't restore case class). So either you should modify your type class

```
trait Converter[T] {
  type Out
  def convert(t:T): Out
}
```

or you need two type classes: your original `Converter` and

```
trait HListConverter[T <: HList] {
  type Out <: HList
  def convert(t:T): Out
}
```

Moreover, currently your `Converter` is pretty rough. It transforms every `T` into `Datastructure` instead of into specific subtypes of `Datastructure`. This means `Generic` will be able to restore case classes only of shapes

```
MyClass(x: Datastructure) 
MyClass(x: Datastructure, y: Datastructure) 
...
```

Is it really what you want? If so then ok, if not and you need

```
MyClass(x: Str) 
MyClass(x: Num, y: Incc) 
...
```

then again you need

```
trait Converter[T] {
  type Out
  def convert(t:T): Out
}
```

Instead of `HListConverter` you can use standard `shapeless.ops.hlist.Mapper`.

Comment: oh you are correct, I do not want to transforms every T into Datastructure; I want to find the correct subtypes of Datastructure